# CKEDITOR: How to add additional input to image upload form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, ckeditor

I just spent whole day trying to add additional input to a image upload form in CKEditor dialog. I need to send some value through post when image is uploaded. 
I've tried to add input manualy but of course this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here is my javascript

```
        CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
            var dialogName = ev.data.name; 
            var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition; 
              if (dialogName == 'image') {
                    dialogDefinition.onShow = function () { 
                        var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
                        var element = dialog.getElement();
                        var iframe = $(element).find('iframe.cke_dialog_ui_input_file');
                        var form = iframe.contents().find('form');
                        form.append('<input type="hidden" name="addInput" value="myvalue">');
                    }; 
                } 
        });
```

Comment: here is how do I add. But it don't pass to form. Have you found solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/40867123/3894584