# how to pass custom fields to $_POST or $_GET in CKEdtior Upload dialog?

Tags: php, ckeditor

For example I have add 2 inputs:

```
infoTab.add( {
                   type : 'text',
                   hidden : false,
                   id: 'image_group',
                   label: 'A',
                   default: ''

               });

               infoTab.add( {
                   type : 'text',
                   hidden : false,
                   id: 'image_size',
                   label: 'B,',
                   default: ''
               });
```

I fill these fields mannualy with random data and when I press "Send it to the server" I can't see in $_POST or $_GET these values or keys? What I must change to send this custom form elements to Server?
Thank you!

Comment: depending on browser inspector - this fields are sibling for common in dialog; but CKEditor do not add it to form located in `iframe`